# Error in running JavaScript from an XSL file

Tags: javascript, xslt

I have an XSL file which has a JavaScript function. I am getting an error in calling the JavaScript function, and I cant understand what's wrong. Please help.

Here is the JavaScript:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                              xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
    <xsl:import href="page_layout.xsl"/>
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <msxsl:script language="JScript">
        <![CDATA[
        function EnableSubmit() 
        {
        alert ("Hello there");
        }
    ]]>
    </msxsl:script>
```

Here is the form which calls the function -

```
< form action="NewUserNavigation" method="post" name="NewUserNavigationForm">
            < input name="eventName" type="hidden" value="NewUserNavigationEvent"/>
            < div class="sansIcon">
            < input type="checkbox" name="chk" onClick="EnableSubmit()">I accept< /input>
            < /div>
            < div class="buttonBarPage">
            < input name="Submit" class="primary" type="submit" value="Continue"/>
            < /div>
        < /form>
```

Both the form and the JavaScript is a part of the same .xml file.

Comment: Aren't `msxsl:script` tags for declaring scripts for use internally by the XSL only, rather than for outputting JavaScript? If I'm right, you should presumably see that, in your output, the function doesn't appear and, when called, you get an error in your console. Replace the `msxsl:script` tag with a usual `<script>` tag. As a sidenote, in JavaScript it's better to put the opening curly brace on the same line, not the next one.

Answer (score 1):

**You misunderstand the role and meaning of [`<msxsl:script>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302079.aspx).**

It allows javascript functions that it contains to be called *during the transformation* -- not before or after the transformation has been run.

You actually want the XSLT transformation that creates the form also to *generate* the javascript text as its result, so that its functions are accessible by the form.

Comment: I made the following changes, but it still doesn't work...

    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">     <xsl:import href="page_layout.xsl"/>     
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>      
    
    <xsl:script language="javascript">         
    <![CDATA[         
    function EnableSubmit() {         
    alert ("Hello there");         
    }]]>     
    </xsl:script>

The form remains the same

Comment: @ASG: There isn't anything like an `<xsl:script>` instruction in XSLT. Please, read well my answer and try to undestand what it means -- you din't need anything like `msxsl:script` -- you *must* generate the script in the output of the transformation.

Comment: @dimitre... thanks much for your help. but i am new to this. can u help me by sharing the code?

Comment: @ASG: I will gladly do that, provided you specify precisely the source XML document and the precise wanted result (which should contain your javascript functions -- among other things) from the transformation.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me

```js
var sh = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.Popup("hello")
```